# TypeScript: Require one of two destructured params

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, destructuring, required-field

When creating an interface that requires one of two possible properties to be set, type unions are helpful:

```js
enum Plans { bronze, silver, gold }
type Plan = keyof typeof Plans;

interface CreateSubscriptionBase {
  /** User's id */
  uid: string;
  /** Plan id */
  planName: Plan;
}

interface CreateSubscriptionPaymentMethod extends CreateSubscriptionBase {
  /** Payment Method id */
  paymentMethod: string;
}

interface CreateSubscriptionSource extends CreateSubscriptionBase {
  /** Source id */
  source: string;
}

export type CreateSubscriptionParams =
    CreateSubscriptionPaymentMethod
  | CreateSubscriptionSource

const sParams = {
  uid: 'foo',
  planName: 'bronze',
  source: 'source',
} as CreateSubscriptionParams

const pParams = {
  uid: 'foo',
  planName: 'bronze',
  paymentMethod: 'paymentMethod',
} as CreateSubscriptionParams
```

However, when using that interface to destructure function parameters, all of a sudden things go screwy:

```js
function createSubscription({ uid, planName, paymentMethod, source }: CreateSubscriptionParams) {
  return 'hi'
}
```

```
example.ts:36:46 - error TS2339: Property 'paymentMethod' does not exist on type 'CreateSubscriptionParams'.

36   { uid, planName, paymentMethod, source }: CreateSubscriptionParams,
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

example.ts:36:61 - error TS2339: Property 'source' does not exist on type 'CreateSubscriptionParams'.

36   { uid, planName, paymentMethod, source }: CreateSubscriptionParams,
                                     ~~~~~~
```

How can we pull that off?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript compiler cannot decompose in such a way. When you use a union of types, it tries to find common fields as you see. Because union means this OR this object. Not this AND this object.

Possibly, you should rewrite your interfaces. In [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) you can find an example which can inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [some type guards with rest parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=7&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=63&pc=2#code/PTAEBsFMBcHIGdQEsC2BDA5kgdpU8B7FPNAB1NGgE9TJ4AoHaSAJwDM0BjPAYQFd40Iq1CQAHs2wATRACVInAiykAeQSxwYANKDTYqAPlABvUAF9G2Zuy54AynwBG8ThtLQkBbKImRpchSVVdU0dPUMTCz8%20FFAABQ1uRGN6UFBHFi8ALzwAXlAAZgAGLVT8JHAANxF8gBYSsowCcClQfIBGIoaLempaePA9NtAAa0gqAjZKGkhJ%20MS6ektrDm5QAFUkKTi0FjQUZLK%20LYAufGgNbAwAbnoeplZVvB2qYisAWRgACwJt3f3DmlSGhXn5oJ9oD8pGdTKdzpcMOYANqwLawAC6t3uVketlAdgIfBY3B2ewOJjKhCJ3BhyGh8M0yNRUgxWKWDxsax4LEgaGYDmcriQ7k82AAQmh4HgUkDBtgAHL7SBnOJy25pRR8UheAD8ZxCVzZvRmoG5vP5Thcbg8XlJALaZTNfMgAqtwpt4sleAAZBstnbyb6ABQvN7g76-AOIAA%20%20MJxMgUYAlEtFNhBMh4KGwRCocMg8CyfATmU0tmPhG-kWyrGCdTE-8DkmzoX7UhEOXw5DI43ELkDGUAISDgu93QdkFh3M9otJgB0wNBFe7rW93qHo6L47j9eTc6pCdu9DTGc4fM4XwAgtBoFwvgBRFiZFgOtKjpfQAAqM0VxDOYwmKZO2nKt7VjAC5jrBNkzaAc0jfVhnzOR9n2bUBcGqF9%20wpeD4JPZpIDnRClCDYiWCTdVcMoL5MgAd3QyB6JQkiAAMeEJFp0IIaBdBvO9QAAEmMRcw2-Whf0gMxKAIUBOAEIRiBYFiKNLcwjykBRBh5UA2D4bBOA9XjbwvYDK03AEzk2UDA3iScc0rZMVUyFB20gFR%20EEYQWAHDTOC0vBdP0wy%20WMr4oO4cyDks-0x19cKG1nJyiFc9z5K8gd6ElKh9J0vSDNFIy707MTICDMpTGOKQdDnGqRLBErzGi6zEGDUyVyjUBa3jElexTNCEmSqVUs8xSjBlUAeWgIlvHbNqoXfUSZhTXCdUKky7OXeaKq2arao2r8TTMecz2gC8gxOi9r1C5iWCDWA6s235YCTZb4LOEK73ioNtqq0AaoXfaGqOucLq%20c7zyvPiLxuu6D24Z6VJ6LKcsC-KvFknlnVdIURS8b7ZMJbVsB0Ug5QknRKt2gGPyBs4nQtQVrVFRz5kGtzsaZrwxrKE8eNhek5JGkQpPyNBaLQJAeI%209aaZmfHKb%20vbZf6I7KJARW51AKg0CkKQ0C1nW9Y15B0CwXBQFovApC2ZBoB5rwM3gS0ccM-JjCkyV8WdznsEoybpvwb33VFI1QCAA)  to make the optional params ambiguous.

```js
// let's imagine some app types
interface Customer extends Record<string, any> { }
interface Subscription extends Record<string, any> {}
enum Prices {
  bronze = 30,
  silver = 40,
  gold = 100,
}

type Plan = keyof typeof Prices

interface UidParams {
  uid: string;
}

interface PaymentMethodParams {
  paymentMethod: { id: string }['id'];
}

interface SourceParams {
  source: { id: string }['id'];
}

interface CreateSubscriptionBase {
  planName: Plan;
  coupon?: string;
}

type CreateSubscriptionParams =
  CreateSubscriptionBase & UidParams & (PaymentMethodParams | SourceParams)

const isPaymentMethod = (params:
    PaymentMethodParams
  | SourceParams): params is PaymentMethodParams =>
  !!(params as PaymentMethodParams).paymentMethod &&
  !(params as SourceParams).source;

const catchAttachError =
  (paymentTypeName: keyof PaymentMethodParams | keyof SourceParams) =>
    (error: Error): never => {
      console.error(error);
      throw new Error(`Could not attach ${paymentTypeName} to customer`);
    };

declare function attachPaymentMethod(params: UidParams & PaymentMethodParams): Promise<Customer>
declare function attachSource(params: UidParams & SourceParams): Promise<Customer>

async function attachPaymentType(
  { uid, ...paymentType }: UidParams & (PaymentMethodParams | SourceParams)
): Promise<Customer> {
  return isPaymentMethod(paymentType)
    ? attachPaymentMethod({ uid, ...paymentType }).catch(catchAttachError('paymentMethod'))
    : attachSource({ uid, ...paymentType }).catch(catchAttachError('source'));
}

async function createSubscription({ coupon, planName, uid, ...paymentType }: CreateSubscriptionParams): Promise<Subscription> {
  const { id: customer } = await attachPaymentType({ uid, ...paymentType });
  // ... yadda yadda ... imagine we did it
  const subscription = {} as Subscription;
  return subscription;
}
```